# Improving Ruby Sequel Model Code

Tags: ruby, model, sequel

I have the following Model that retrieves an object known as `GroupUser`, which are as the name suggestions, a Group of Users:

```
[# < Model::GroupUser @values = {: id => 24,
  : user_id => 8,
  : group_id => 3,
  : from_group_id => 3
} > , # < GroupUser @values = {: id => 27,
  : user_id => 9,
  : group_id => 3,
  : from_group_id => 3
} > , # < GroupUser @values = {: id => 36,
  : user_id => 7,
  : group_id => 3,
  : from_group_id => 3
} > ]
```

I'd like to turn this `GroupUser` into their respective e-mail addresses (each `User` has an associated `email` property)

So I did the following:

```
users = []
group_users = Model::GroupUser.where(:group_id => self[:address]).map(:user_id)
group_users.each do |user|
  users << Model::User.where(id: user).first.email
end
users
```

It works.. But I feel like with how many elegant ways to do stuff in Ruby, this could be written in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes to mind is this, essentially packing everything into a single map loop:

```
users = Model::GroupUser.where(:group_id => self[:address]).map do |group_user|
  Model::User.where(id: group_user[:user_id]).first.email
end
```

If you set up the associations in your Sequel models, you can use `group_user.user.first.email` within the loop. Also, in that case, you may want to eager load the association for better performance: `users = Model::GroupUser.eager(:user).where...`.

Comment: Actually yeah, the associations are all setup! Let me try your suggestion for the association

Comment: Sweet, `group_user.user.first.email` worked! Is there a way to do it without the `map`, but instead as a one-liner?

Comment: You could define a method `user_email` on `Model::GroupUser`. Then then its just Model::GroupUser...map(&:user_email). To completely avoid the map, I think you'd have to join the tables manually.